# IE sometimes requests homepage (site root) at the same time as other page

Tags: html, internet-explorer, web-applications, browser

My site consists of a sequence of form-submits.  A very small number of browsers, less than 1% and perhaps only some IE browsers, will request the home page at the same time as every content page.  With one of the problem browsers, typical section of IIS logs looks like this:

```
15-Mar-13   11:07:39 PM POST    /content.asp
15-Mar-13   11:07:39 PM GET /mainstyle.css
15-Mar-13   11:07:39 PM GET /images/logo.gif
15-Mar-13   11:07:39 PM GET /images/bar.gif
15-Mar-13   11:07:39 PM GET /images/fill.gif
15-Mar-13   11:07:39 PM GET /images/pbtop.gif
15-Mar-13   11:07:39 PM GET /images/hr.gif
15-Mar-13   11:07:39 PM GET /index.htm
15-Mar-13   11:07:39 PM GET /images/pbbottom.gif
```

The request to /index.htm is spurious (and causing a lot of trouble).  (IIS logs "/index.htm" even when the request is just for "/".)  Because the IIS logs are only resolved down to the full second, and items don't appear in exact sequence, it's hard to be sure if the strange extra request for index.htm is being triggered by the preceding page, or by something in the page that is loading.

My first thought was maybe there is a blank src="" in the page somewhere, but there isn't, at least not in any browser I use to test.  It drives me nuts, because I can't duplicate it, and it only happens with a tiny fraction of users.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this, or any guess what could cause it?

Comment: One possibility I wondered about -- could ad blocking software be stripping out image names, leaving src="" in the HTML?  My app has no ads, but it has a transparent gif.  No problem if the whole image tag were stripped, but if just the image name were removed that would cause the observed problem.

Comment: Yes, we experience currently a very similar issue with 5 PC (XP x86 with SP3) out of 10000. It occurs with IE (6 and 8) but not with Firefox or Chrome. Even when Internet Explorer does GET a simple **blank** html page, it requests next the root webpage "/" too. It does not depend on the sources of the page. Usually, it's due to an Add-On but, in our case, the problem still occurs in "Safe Mode with network support" and with IE run without Add-Ons (Right-click > Browse without Add-Ons".

Answer (score 1):

Disable the "Content Advisor" in IE, via "Tools-> Internet Options-> Content Tab"...

If you don't have access to the button because the "Content Advisor" is protected by a password, you can try this: http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Content-Advisor-Password-in-Internet-Explorer.

I had the very same issue and this solved it as I reported on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/86c5130a-d4fa-471b-87b1-7bf51c36eb9e

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the similar problem. In my case, it turns out that src="" results in the issue.

Here's the thing.

I request the server some images to make the waterfall effect. I use JavaScript template to render the items. Here's the problem in my template:

```
<img src="" data-src="{{imgSrc}}">
```

I put the image source in data-src first and use JavaScript to set the src attribute later, leaving src="" there. Looks like IE6-8 will request to my site root when I append the image tags to the DOM.

And interestingly, if I do the scrolling very fast, appending a lot of images in a short time, the request to my site root will only be sent once.

But if I scroll slowly, each time the `<img>`s being appended, a request to the site root is sent by IE.

My solution is simply to remove src="" and that's it.

As [user1207313](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1207313/user1207313) mentioned, you don't write src="" but maybe some plugins make this happen. That's also a possibility. Because you said only a small amount of users send the request.